# How to Modify Joomla Registration Confirmation Email

Tags: user, emails, registration

I'm currently trying to enhance/streamline the User Registration process on our Joomla website, however I've run into a snag on modifying the User Confirmation email.  I have figured out how to change the *text* (extensions -> language(s) -> overrides) of the email, but not the *html* of the email.  I'm trying to use some basic styling and more strategic placement of the links to make it more abundantly obvious what to do.

Is there any way to do this without installing an extension? My site is getting pretty bloated and I would prefer to not install an extension or plugin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The text is the HTML of the email. You can have HTML code in that text formatted the way you want. There is no other place where you can actually change the HTML of that email.

Update: Open the `components/com_users/models/registration.php` file and add `true` at the end of **each and every** `JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail` function call. For example, you should change the following line:

```
$return = JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($data['mailfrom'], $data['fromname'], $row->email, $emailSubject, $emailBody);
```

to

```
$return = JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($data['mailfrom'], $data['fromname'], $row->email, $emailSubject, $emailBody, true);
```

Note that there are 4 occurrences, so you should change them all. Also note that this is a core modification, so proceed with caution.

If it still doesn't work, then change `$emailBody` (or `$emailBodyAdmin`) to `html_entity_decode($emailBody)` (or `html_entity_decode($emailBodyAdmin)`).

Comment: Thanks, you understood my question right on.  The only problem is that I tried inputting HTML and it didn't work.  For example, I tried to wrap text in an <a>: `<a href="%s">Register</a>`.  And it showed up as literally `<a href="{url here}">Register</a>`.  It doesn't appear to be working the way you said it should.

Comment: And by "Literally" i mean you could see the text "<a href..." in the email.

Comment: I have updated the answer - please check now.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer.  It does work!  However, won't these changes go away after the next Joomla version?  Is there any way to make sure these changes persist?

Comment: Yes, by using a plugin. Sorry, but you either get 'bloated' sites or hacked together ones. You decide.

Comment: I think this is coming in Joomla! 4