# Enable HTML for the user registration e-mail

Tags: joomla-3.x, email-template

I'm trying to put together a simly e-mail template which will be send to newly registered users on my page.

It should contain an image in the header and the standard welcome text for new users which Joomla sends by default.

**Does anybody know, if there's a way how to enable HTML(and maybe CSS) for the standard registration E-mail please?**

I created a language override for the particular Constant: **COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ACTIVATION_BODY**
And I added the HTML code into the override as well. I just can't figure out, how to tell Joomla, that it should render the Image instead of the HTML code :eek:

I tired to set $mailer value in the configuration.php of my site to: public **$mailer = 'isHTML(TRUE)';** but that didn't help.

I have the Joomla! 3.6.4 version currently on my server.

I already searched for an answer on this forum, but couldn't find anything suitable for my case.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably not a duplicate but related: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/16993/120

Comment: There's a similar question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10863711/1983389

Comment: I think it is coming in Joomla! 4

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use Acymailing.

They have included a functionality that allows you to use your own HTML email for any of the Joomla standard emails.

Comment: I didn't know this, nice!